# componentWillUpdate is called infinitely, even with conditional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-loop, react-class-based-component

I have a class component, called **ListOfItems.js**, that lists a bunch of objects like so:

```
class ListOfItems extends Component {
  construction (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      objectList: []
    }
  }
}

// This gets the list of objects to display
componentDidMount() {
   this.getObjectList();
}

componentDidUpdate(_prevProps, prevState) {

  if( this.state.ObjectList !== prevState.ObjectList) {

     // this is called infinitely
     console.log("entered");
     this.getObjectList();
  }
}

getObjectList = () => {
  const input = { id_for_this_list: id }

  fetch( connectToApi, {
     method: "PUT",
     headers: { //stuff}
     body: JSON.stringify(input)
  })
     .then(res => //)
     .then(result => //)
     .catch(err=>{console.error(err)});
}
```

Inside of **Object.js** (the file for each object displayed in ListOfItems), I have a **delete functionality**, where if the user selected the "x" icon on the object, that object is deleted from the list. An instance of the Object.js inside of ListOfItems.js looks like this:

```
{this.state.objectList.map(item) => {
  <Object 
    objectList={this.objectList}
    data={item}
    //few other props here
  >
}
```

Once I enter this ListOfItems.js, the componentWillUpdate is called infinitely, even with the conditional. I'd like it to be called only once -- when the user deletes an Object on the ListOfItems page.

Comment: You are using a referential equality check rather than a deep equality check. You need to update `this.state.ObjectList !== prevState.ObjectList` to compare the values of each array rather than the reference.

Comment: Thanks for your input! How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I guess `getObjectList` is the one updating the state. Can you provide it's implementation?

Comment: Yes, once the user clicks "x" on the Object, that object is removed from the list by calling a delete request to the service. getObjectList() calls a get request to a service that returns the list. Let me specify its implementation above. What I would like to do is to trigger the componentWillUpdate() when the user clicks "x" on the Object.